# How to save date in unix timestamp in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, date

I have one column as closed_date and data type is timestamp. I want to add the date in unix timestamp e.g. 1556801668. I don't know how to do that in Laravel.

Comment: What does this *how to do that in Laravel* mean?

Comment: Try using [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use php `strtotime()` function to convert time.

**Example**

```php
$time = '2019-01-01'

$timeStamp = strtotime($time);

// will output 1546300800
```

Comment: how to do it in Laravel?

Comment: @Trupti it's a PHP function that you can use in any PHP scripts.

Answer (score 3):

I you want to do this within the model, you can use castings:

```
protected $casts = [
    'closed_date' => 'timestamp',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Date string, for instance, you can create a `Carbon` object and store it directly into database.

Laravel will convert that object to the correct type for the database.